Let $M$ and $N$ be manifolds and consider $u: M \to N$, how to define the partial derivative $\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial x_\alpha}$?
If I have two Riemannian manifolds $M^n$ and $N^l$ and a differentiable function $u: M \to N$ and I choose $p \in M$ and a coordinate chart $(U_p)$ around $p$ and a coordinate chart $V_{u(p)}$ around $u(p)$ such that $u(U_p) \subset V_{u(p)}$ then what is the meaning of the expression
$$\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial x_\alpha} $$
here $(x_\alpha)$ are the coordinates of $U_p$ and $(u^i)$ the coordinates of $V_{u(p)}$. I am confused beacuse $u^i$ is a function from $N$ to $\mathbb{R}^{l}$ and $x_\alpha$ from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, so I don't know how to make sense of it.
For context I'm studying harmonic maps, and this derivative comes up in the definition of the dirichlet energy. For $u \in C^2(M,N)$ we define, using normal coordinates
$$ e(u)(x) = \sum_{\alpha ,\beta}g^{\alpha \beta} (x) h_{ij}(u(x)) \frac{\partial u^i}{\partial x_\alpha} \frac{u^j}{\partial x_\beta} $$
Here, $(x_\alpha)$ are the coordinates of $U_p$ and $(u^i)$ are the coordinates of $V_{u(p)}$. and the energy is
$$\int_M e(u) dVol_g $$

No, $u^i$ are not coordinates. That is shorthand for $v^i\circ u$, where $v$ are the coordinates on $V$.

When I have to recall or derive a formula with respect to coordinates in either linear algebra and differential geometry, I prefer to start with a geometric (abstract) formulation and let the version in coordinates fall naturally out of it. The story below is a bit longer than using coordinates from the start but I find it an easier way to remember how to do the calculations correctly.
Here, the goal is to derive both a concept and formula for the derivative of a map. The mantra is that the simplest type of derivative in this situation is the directional derivative. This in turn is simply, for each $p \in M$ and $v \in T_pM$, the derivative of the map along a parameterized curve whose velocity at $p$ is $v$.
So here's how it goes: There exists a parameterized curve $c: (-T,T) \rightarrow M$ such that $c(0)=p$ and $c'(0)=v$. Then $u\circ c: (-T,T) \rightarrow N$ is a parameterized curve in $N$ whose velocity at $f(p)$ is $(u\circ c)'(0)$. This defines a linear map from a velocity vector on $M$ to one on $N$,
\begin{align*}
u_*: T_pM &\rightarrow T_{u(p)}N\\
v &\rightarrow (u\circ c)'(0).
\end{align*}
Now we introduce coordinates. Given coordinates $(x^1, \dots, x^n)$, there is a coordinate basis of $T_pM$ (consisting of velocity vectors of the coordinate curves) whose elements are often denoted
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}
$$
Similarly, coordinates $(y^1,\dots, y^n)$ induce a basis of $T_{u(p)}N$, denoted
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}.
$$
From here, it's pure linear algebra.
Since $u_*: T_pM \rightarrow T_{f(p)}$ is linear, there exists a matrix $L$ such that
$$ u_*\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha} = L_\alpha^i\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}. $$
It is natural to denote
$$
L = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
$$
and its components by
$$
L^i_\alpha = \frac{\partial u^i}{\partial x^\alpha}.
$$
Therefore, given any
$$ v = v^\alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha},
$$
we have
$$
u_*v = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}v = \left(\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial x^\alpha}v^\alpha\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}. $$
As for the energy functional, the obvious (and only way) to contract the matrix
$$\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial x^\alpha}$$
into a scalar in a coordinate-independent way using only the metrics $g$ and $h$ is the formula for $e$ you wrote. Note, however, that formula is valid with respect to any coordinates on $M$ and $N$. Normal coordinates are not needed. Normal coordinates become useful when you do computations involving $e$, such as deriving the Euler-Lagrange equations. The neat part of the harmonic map equation is that it uses the Levi-Civita connection on $M$ but not the one on $N$.
The other advantage of the formulation above is that it works without any change if you use frames (not necessarily orthonormal) instead of coordinates. And again, this all falls out very naturally from the definition of a directional derivative at a point and the fact that it is linear with respect to the direction (i.e., tangent vector). Note, in particular, that although the pushforward map is used in the discussion above, I did not need to remember its definition.

Let $(U,\phi=(x^1,\dots, x^n))$ be a coordinate chart around a point $p\in M$ and let $(V,\psi=(y^1,\dots, y^m))$ be a coordinate chart around $u(p)\in N$ such that $u$ maps $U$ into $V$.
Then, we can consider the composite function $u^i:=y^i\circ (u|_U)$ defined on $U$. Also, for any function $f:U\to\Bbb{R}$, one defines
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\alpha}}:U\to\Bbb{R},\qquad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\alpha}}:=\left(\partial_{\alpha}(f\circ\phi^{-1})\right)\circ\phi,
\end{align}
i.e it is the $\alpha^{th}$ partial derivative of the chart-representative function $f\circ\phi^{-1}$, followed by a final composition with $\phi$ so that it becomes a function on $U$ instead of $\phi[U]\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ (btw sometimes, people may omit this final composition with $\phi$ in their definition… it’s really a matter of preference whether one wants it or not).

So, putting everything together, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\equiv\frac{\partial (y^i\circ u)}{\partial x^{\alpha}}:=\left(\partial_{\alpha}(y^i\circ u\circ\phi^{-1})\right)\circ\phi.
\end{align}
This is a function $U\to\Bbb{R}$ (or $\phi[U]\to\Bbb{R}$ if you omit the final composition with $\phi$).
